# How do you get a newly generated random string inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, random

Using the for loop, I expect this code to generate a new random string. I want to get a new string every time I run the for loop.

This is my current implementation:

```
let hex = 'ABCDEF0123456789';
let res = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    res += hex.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length));
    // console.log(i);
}
```

How can I change it, so that the value of **res** is different for every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean that you want to put your code in a function and call the function?

```
function res() {
  let hex = 'ABCDEF0123456789';
  let res = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    res += hex.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length));
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(res()) // => one value
console.log(res()) // => another value
console.log(res()) // => a third value
```

Comment: No I want to get values different without re-running the code. I want to get values different every time when I print it.

Comment: A then you have to use a getter if you feel ill at ease with calling a function? (Or are you not familiar with functions?)

Comment: Please help me with the code?

Comment: A better solution would be generating a random integer, then convert it to hex: `return (Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0).toString(16)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let hex = 'ABCDEF0123456789';
let res = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  res = hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)];
  console.log(res);
};
```

Comment: No, that. would only print part of res as you're a building it...